# Google Ads: Using one form submission to track two campaign conversions in two different languages

Tags: ads, google-ads-api

I'm new to `google ads` and need to apply conversion tracking to a form submission on my site. The site offers translation in two locales (`en`, `de`). I've created two marketing campaigns for corresponding regions. So far I've integrated the english ad conversion into my site and tested it with the `google tag assistant`, which works. I am having two question:

1. `Google ads` seems to track the ad campaign's `id` on my site. How does it know, if someone who submitted a form, truly clicked on the `ad`? Does the `ad click` send info to the site that "this visitor came here by clicking on this ad"? Does this function handle it?

   ```
    gtag('event', 'conversion', {
        'send_to': "id...",
        'event_callback': callback
    });
   ```
2. How does `google ads` know, wether the visitor comes from the `en` ad or the `de` ad? I am thinking about triggering the corresponding `conversion id` depending on the `locale` of the visitor but this would exclude for example german visitors with `en` language set in their browser and would count them as conversions of the `en` campaign.

How do you handle this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user clicks on one of your ads and is redirected to the corresponding landing page on your site, the `gtag` snippet will extract information about the click from the URL via the `gclid` parameter and set that information in a first party cookie (currently called `_gcl_aw`) scoped to your domain.

Once a user does actually convert on your site and the conversion tracking function is called, it will check for the presence of that first party cookie and use it to determine whether the user came from Google Ads–and if so, to which campaign / adgroup / ad it should be attributed to.

That means that just having a single conversion set up in Google Ads is fine. You'll be able to figure out which campaigns drove how many conversions as long as the user doesn't suppress the required cookies or JS snippets.